# Post a data to iframe(aspx) to capture it in Page load of aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, iframe

I have a HTML page and an iframe(aspx page) in it as shown below.

**Mypage.htm**

```
<div>
<iframe name="Frame1" id="ff1" src="http://example.com/example.aspx" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="600" width="500" style="text-decoration:none;" marginwidth="5"></iframe>
</div>
```

This Mypage.htm will be given as a link from other pages where user clicks and Mypage.htm opens in new tab.

I want to post data to the iframe. posted data is "website"= "true"(posted data is just an identification and is fixed) . The posted data is captured in page_load of the aspx page which is in iframe.

So now i am confused like how to post data to frame and at which event. I should be able to get posted data in the page load of aspx page.
How it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Simply just use a query string instead of the post data:

```
<div>
    <iframe name="Frame1" id="ff1" src="http://example.com/example.aspx?website=true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="600" width="500" style="text-decoration:none;" marginwidth="5"></iframe>
</div>
```

And in `Page_Load` check for `Request.QueryString["website"]` (instead of `Request.Form["website"]`).

Comment: @ITresearcher - you just simply can't in webforms (aspx)... but otherwise you would do it like this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/post-data-to-an-iframe/